# Azure IoT Hub message routing Routing query to identify change in desired property only

Tags: azure, azure-iot-hub

I am trying to use Azure IoT hub message routing on Device Twin change event.

I would like to get the notification of Device Twin change - only if any thing in desired property is changed. I don't want the notification if reported property is changed.

Can you please help with the query? any reference to documentation?

Answer (score 2):

Routing query:

```
is_object($body.properties.desired)
```

Comment: This condition would be true if the reported property is changed - right? because it is only checking whether it is object or not. right ? or am I missing something?

Comment: this condition is *true* if the message body contains the complex object *properties.desired*, for example: *{"properties":{"desired":{"color":"RED"}}}*

Comment: Right. Now this condition would be true if the color property changed or does not changed. What I am looking for is - when the Color property changed - then only need notification.

Comment: That's right and also when the *color* property has been removed (or property *desired* has been removed)

Comment: note, that the removing all *desired* properties can be done { "properties": { "desired":null}}

Comment: @Ganesh does this work for any the change in color property? I also have the same requirement as yours and unfortunately the messages are routed even if the property value doesn't change